# How to go about editing a local text file with a JavaScript .js file for configuration settings

Tags: javascript, file-io, config

I have been creating a web application (that I would like to be able to run locally as well) that is starting off as a basic cash register. I would like to create a text or .js file to save variables to so that the user can leave the browser and then come back with the same amount of cash in their cash register as when they left.

Therefore, I must be able to pull the variable from this file when the program starts, and then put in the new variable when the program ends.

Is this possible? If so, how?

---

Another note: Also, I'd rather not use cookies unless it is my only option, because the user could accidentally delete their cookies, and all of their settings are then deleted.

Comment: Javascript can't access files directly. Use a cookie or LocalStorage.

Comment: It's a way for Javascript programs to store data in the browser. It's like cookies, but only accessible to the browser, not sent to the server, so it doesn't have as small size limits.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar I'm now using localStorage and it works!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't access real files from JavaScript, but you can use LocalStorage as a storage location for JavaScript data instead.